# Does my application considered as restful?

Tags: rest

I created a page called api.aspx
I am displaying my output using a JSON serialize. 
Each type of function is based on query string. For example:

```
If Request.QueryString("action") = "getMember"
```

Then from there, I do a

```
Request.QueryString("memberid")
```

For the variable I required for my function to work. Lastly the output is displayed as JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **REST**, there should be no verbs in the `URI`, especially no things such as `?action=getMember`. The core REST principle is [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) - which says that the state of the application is represented by the state of its resources.

Furthermore, the application should use a uniform interface - that is, use the standard HTTP methods `POST`, `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` for **CRUD** operations respectively.

So, such a `member` resource from your example should be accessed via `GET` request to a URI such as:

```
http://example.com/api/member/{memberId}
```

Where {memberId} is path parameter that represents the memberId.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's not restful since the url scheme is depending on query string parameters. For a real restful API the url's shoud be http://asite/member/2 and not be named.

If you want to make your api truly restful, use the URL routing from ASP.NET MVC, it's possible to integrate with webforms.